# generating pdf with MPDF, non breaking space displayed as unsupoprted characters

Tags: fonts, char, mpdf

Using **Mpdf 8.0.8**, I create a document with custom font which displays fine, except for non-breaking spaces, which appear as crossed-squares:[image]

When opening my font with *FontForge* I see that `uni00A0` char is defined (it's blank but there is no cross)

**Here is the code calling Mpdf:**

```
public function getPdfData($values, $medias, $locale = 'fr_FR')
{
    $sessionLocale = $this->translator->getLocale();
    $this->translator->setLocale($locale);
    $html = $this->twig->render('@Pim/testPdf.html.twig');
    $this->translator->setLocale($sessionLocale);

    $defaultConfig = (new \Mpdf\Config\ConfigVariables())->getDefaults();
    $fontDirs = $defaultConfig['fontDir'];

    $defaultFontConfig = (new \Mpdf\Config\FontVariables())->getDefaults();
    $fontData = $defaultFontConfig['fontdata'];

    $fontData = $fontData + [
            'myhelvet' => [
                'R' => 'helvetlight.ttf',
                'I' => 'helvetthick.ttf',
            ],
            'timeslightitalic' => [
                'R' => 'timeslightitalic.ttf'
            ]
        ];
    $defaultFont = 'myhelvet';

    $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf([
        'orientation' => 'L',
        'margin_left' => 0,
        'margin_right' => 0,
        'margin_top' => 1,
        'margin_bottom' => 0,
        'fontDir' => array_merge($fontDirs, [
            __DIR__ . '/../Resources/public/fonts',
        ]),
        'fontdata' => $fontData,
        'default_font' => $defaultFont,
        'mode' => '+aCJK',
        "autoScriptToLang" => true,
        "autoLangToFont" => true,
    ]);
    $mpdf->addFontDirectory(__DIR__ . '/../Resources/public/fonts');
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
    $pdfData = $mpdf->Output('', 'S');

    return $pdfData;
}
```

**And here goes the html view that cannot render a non breaking space created by Php NumberFormatter:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>

<div style="font-family: myhelvet">Formatting a number: {{ '20000'|numberFormatLocale('fr_FR') }}</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Finally, the php code generating the breaking space (a Twig filter):**

```
public static function numberFormatLocale($number, $locale)
{
    $formatter = new \NumberFormatter($locale, \NumberFormatter::DECIMAL);

    return $formatter->format($number);
}
```

Comment: Show your code. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366988/what-does-mcve-mean

Comment: @Finwe Thanks. I edited my question to show my code.

Comment: Without the HTML data, it is hardly complete.

Comment: @Finwe Here goes the HTML, which is very basic (the breaking space is generated by PHP though)

Comment: @Finwe I can add a screenshot of the opened font in FontForge if you wish

Comment: @Finwe Did you find a moment to take a look at that problem ? I forgot to mention that when I use default font, the nb space displays fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of the NumberFormatter is not `U+00A0`, but `0xE2 0x80 0xAf`, or `U+202F` - *NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE* which is most likely not supported by the font.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and your insight. I spent hours on this problem but my understanding of fonts/ char codes is quite limited. I have added the char with FontForge in my font, which solved the problem.